# Subversion repository grows not as much as expected

Tags: svn, repository

Today I wanted to show a colleague that using windows copy and paste is not a good idea. I have done the following steps:

1. Created a local repository.
2. Checked out that empty repository.
3. Added some files to the checkout location and commited them.
4. Looked at the size of the repository (~ 9 MB).
5. I then copied one Powerpoint file (~ 2 MB) with windows copy and paste, renamed it, and commited it to Subversion. Subversion did not know the file (as expected), so I had to manually add it to Subversion first.
6. After the commit, I expected the repository to grow significantly (> 1 MB), because I have added a new file without history. The result was, that the growth of the repo was only 1 KB.

My questions here are:

- Is that the correct behavior now for Subversion 1.7?
- When did that change? In the past (at least for Subversion 1.5), when you added an exact copy (with windows copy and paste), it was added as a new file to the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading parts of the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html) again, I found (I think) the answer myself. Here is the relevant part of ["How Subversion saves disk space"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deltas)

> Repositories created with Subversion 1.6 or later further enjoy the
>   disk space savings afforded by representation sharing, a feature which
>   allows multiple files or file revisions with identical file content to
>   refer to a single shared instance of that data rather than each having
>   their own distinct copy thereof.

I will do some research about the `creation with Subversion 1.6 or later`, because that would mean that it does not work for repositories migrated from Subversion 1.5.

Comment: You may want dump-load your old repository to benefit from SVN 1.6 and later features and improvements. Please see SVN FAQ at  http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#dumpload.